# Unable to merge dex when used library with Android studio 3.0.1?

Tags: java, android, admob

I am adding Admob(play-services-ads) library and trying to run my code then it is showing some error which is :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

i made so many changes but still facing this problem.

I am using this code:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.applist.carstation"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


 buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

also I am using dependencies is :

```
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
```

I updated version code add multidex enable true but still im getting this error

where i have to change?

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Answer (score 0):

Create Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
}
```

and Add in manifest file

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: i created myApplication class extends with MultiDexApplicatoin but not working

Comment: do you have any suggestion then reply please

Comment: try to clean and File ->invalid cache restart